# Making design in Xmarin Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I want to make a design just like the picture below

[![Example][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gzlj0.png

But I am not sure how to start. I have idea to make it with `Frames` and `Grid`. Something like:

```
<StackLayout>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Frame Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="Gray">
            </Frame>
            <Frame BackgroundColor="LightGray" Grid.Row="2">
           </Frame>
        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>
```

But I have no idea how to make frame re-sizable when clicking on it. I want any kind of start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer anyone from below option:

you can create `custom accordion view` and use it.

1. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/simple-accordion-user-control-in-xamarin-forms/
2. https://kimsereyblog.blogspot.com/2016/10/build-accordion-view-in-xamarinforms.html
3. https://alexdunn.org/2018/04/03/xamarin-tip-build-your-own-accordionview-in-xamarin-forms/